# ExtJS 4 instantiated model has id set to 0

Tags: extjs4

If I define an entity like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Entity', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [ {
        name : 'id',
        type : 'int'
    } ]
});
```

And then instantiate it and output its id with:

```
var entity = Ext.create('MyApp.model.Entity');
console.log(entity.getId());
```

I'm getting `0` for the output. I would expect it to be `undefined`. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two likely causes.

First, because you're using the name `id` for a field. `Ext.data.Model` has the `idProperty` config which defaults to `id`, defining the name of the field to be treated differently than the rest. The `getId` method is the equivalent of `get(idProperty)`.

Second, because the type of `id` is `int`, in which case the default value for the field is 0 (unless you use the `useNull` field config).

I personally try to avoid using `id` for a model property because of its tendency to collide with pretty much everything. I've never had problems using something like `recordId` or something similar.